# How to Convert a LINQ result to DATATABLE?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Is there any way to convert the result of a LINQ expression to a `DataTable` without stepping through each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope there is no way to create it without **stepping** through each element. The Linq expression is evaluated when needed so it will step through each row (for matching and selection).

I think you should try using `DataTable.Select()` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx)) method instead as it returns array of `DataRow` objects that you can add to new table as follows:

```
var rows = [ORIGINAL DATA TABLE].Select("id>5");

var dtb=[ORIGINAL DATA TABLE].Clone();

foreach(DataRow r in rows)
{
    var newRow = dtb.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = r.ItemArray;
    dtb.Rows.Add(newRow);//I'm doubtful if you need to call this or not
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Credit to [this blogger](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevesloka/archive/2008/01/28/linq-to-datatable.aspx), but I've improved on his algorithm here.  Make yourself an extension method:

```
    public static DataTable ToADOTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> varlist)
    {
        DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
        // Use reflection to get property names, to create table
        // column names
        PropertyInfo[] oProps = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
        {
            Type colType = pi.PropertyType; 
            if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, colType));
        }
        foreach (T rec in varlist)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtReturn.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
                dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(rec, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pi.GetValue(rec, null);
            dtReturn.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return (dtReturn);
    }
```

Usage:

```
DataTable dt = query.ToADOTable();
```

Comment: I get this error when using your code: "CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: <and then the class containing your method>" Do you know how to solve this? Thanks for code though, +1

Comment: @Phil - can't tell unless you post the full error text, which should contain a reference to both of the competing methods.  Then you'll know which other method has the same signature.

Comment: That's the thing.. it's the same signature for them both. Really strange! Anyway, here's the signature, some names in Swedish. If you don't know directly I'll just post a question about it. Error Message: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Gruppkoll.App_Code.ConvertToDataTableFromLinqResult.ToADOTable<Gruppkoll.MessageSet>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Gruppkoll.MessageSet>)' and 'Gruppkoll.App_Code.ConvertToDataTableFromLinqResult.ToADOTable<Gruppkoll.MessageSet>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Gruppkoll.MessageSet>)'

Comment: What wrong could it do to post a question about it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013057/error-on-ambigous-reference-points-to-same-method-twice