# Join in LINQ that avoids explicitly naming properties in "new {}"?

Tags: linq, linq-to-dataset

I would like to do something like this:

```
    DataTable q = from c in customers
            join o in orders on c.Key equals o.Key
            into outer
            from j in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { c.*, j.* };
```

The closest I currently got is the following:

```
    var q = from c in customers
            join o in orders on c.Key equals o.Key
            into outer
            from j in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { c, j };
```

I'd like my result (q) to have all the columns from c and j.  both c and j contain a lot of columns, so I'd rather not list them as such:

```
            select new { c.col1, c.col2, etc. }
```

But I basically want the final DataTable to be made up of c.* and j.*.

This answer (not the accepted answer, but the one below it) works if I specify all the c and j columns inside 'select new':
[How to Convert a LINQ result to DATATABLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509290/how-to-convert-a-linq-result-to-datatable)
But I'd like to avoid listing them all.

Comment: This isn't related to datasets. It is just how LINQ works (blasted strong typing with no support for this particular static analysis case!). One option might be: `new { Customer = c, Order = j }`. Note that `new { c.col1 }` is effectively `new { col1 = c.col1 }` by language-magic. Here is a [question I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400212/syntax-of-anonymous-type-without-explicit-keys-new-identifier) about the particular syntax.

Comment: Well, you might be able to do something fancy with reflection to build a dynamic `Expression<Func<T1, T2, T3>>` and use that expression as your select expression.  How exactly you would do that, I don't know.

Comment: Oops, I am sleepy, by my own admission, `new { c, .. }` is effectively the same as `new { Customer = c, .. }`

Comment: With all due respect, every time I read "avoid listing them all" in a question about LINQ or SQL, I get "lazy programmer" vibes.  Sometimes you just need to sit down and crank out a few hundred lines of code, brute force style.

Comment: Norla, if I list all the columns, it means when either of original data-tables gets a new column, I'd have to add it here. It's the same issue as code duplication - a fix made to one function, won't exist in the other. And I'm not the one who would be changing the input DataTables, so that just complicates things.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would prefer to specify the columns manually, because I would like to minimize the impact of underlying layers - database schema, query provider - on my application. But if you *really* want to do this there is a bit of a hacky way to accomplish it.

When your are using entity framework (database first):

```
var qs = ((ObjectQuery)q).ToTraceString();
var ds = new DataSet();
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(qs, new SqlConnection(((EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString));
da.Fill(ds, "Result");
```

The idea is to catch the emitted SQL before it is actually executed and use it to fill a `DataTable` (in a `DataSet`).

With Linq-to-sql is is basically the same, just the way to get the command string and connection string is different:

```
context.GetCommand(q).CommandText
context.Connection.ConnectionString
```

With EF Code-first:

```
q.ToString()
context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's impossible. You can only do this in the way you showed in the question: `select new { c, j };` or by listing all the columns.

There're many other threads on this:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d219ff26-6a8a-49b3-8b41-1ce381b7b278
- [Select all columns after JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861059/select-all-columns-after-join-in-linq)
- [Select All columns for all tables in join + linq join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671765/select-all-columns-for-all-tables-in-join-linq-join)